# Issue for http referrer with Google Translate

Tags: http-referer

I have a page `https://api.xx.com/aa.php`, when I open `aa.php`, it will redirect to `bb.php`.

Normally, the referrer for request `bb.php` is `https://api.xx.com/aa.php`, but I get some error referrer `https://api-xx-com/translate/goog/aa.php`

What happens with the referrer? How to get the correct referrer?

Thank you!